# why i cant draw this polygon using fusion table

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Having problem drawing the following rectangle (polygon) using fusion table. Does anybody know why it doesn't show in the fusion table layer?

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
3.27852177628523660,49.83398437500000000 
3.27852177628523660,107.84179687500000000 
39.32224116462732000,107.84179687500000000 
39.32224116462732000,49.83398437500000000 
3.27852177628523660,49.83398437500000000
</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

I created this query by extracting bound information for a map. you can only extract south-west and north-east bound from map. I calculated the other bounds using these. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the coordinates should be of the form `lng,lat` in KML instead of `lat,lng`

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#polygon